# VBA Outlook SaveAsFile method creates empty file

Tags: vba, outlook

I have to process incoming mail and then save some xls-attachments as files.
So, I get all attachments as

```
For Each att In mail.Attachments
```

(I really have all the attachments in `att` objects - I checked it by comparing `att.FileName` property with my attachment's names - it's ok.) But when I try to save my attachments as files, for example like this:

```
att.SaveAsFile "C:\test.xls"
```

The files are created, but they are always empty. Source files in attachments contain some data, text and pictures, but the saved files are empty.

Comment: What version of Office are you running? Also, are you trying to save **PICTURES** and **TEXT** as .xls files?

Comment: You need to show the code that declares `att` and `mail` and how you are getting those references.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell from your code what the problem might be. Using Outlook 2003, I got this to work just fine for any/all .xls attachments...

```
Sub TestSub()
    Dim mail As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim att As Variant
    Set mail = Application.ActiveInspector
    For Each att In mail.CurrentItem.Attachments
        att.SaveAsFile "P:\test.xls"
    Next att
End Sub
```